# How to configure Custom Health Checks in Adobe AEM 6?

Tags: adobe, aem

I am trying to create custom Health checks in AEM 6.
I have,
1)Created a java class that extends inbuilt HealthCheck class.
2)The class looks like,

```
    //SlingHealthCheck properties
    @SlingHealthCheck(
            name="Annotated Health Check Sample", 
            mbeanName="annotatedHC",
            description="Sample Health Check defined by a java annotation",
            tags={"hcTest"})

    //Component and service annotations
    @Component
    @Service(value=HealthCheck.class)
    public class HealthCheckTestClass implements HealthCheck{
        @Override
        public Result execute() {
            Result result = new Result(Status.CRITICAL,
                    "Hey Something went wrong!!");
            return result;
        }

    }
```

3) I have created a bundle which contains this class.
4)I have installed it in AEM from web console.

I don't know how can I configure it so that I can see the output produced by my custom health check class on AEM web console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the source code of the Apache Sling [Health Check Samples](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/extensions/healthcheck/samples) bundle as an example that creates some custom health checks.

All active HealthCheck services should be visible on the OSGi console page at `/system/console/healthcheck`, as well as from a JMX console. See the [Sling Health Checks](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-health-check-tool.html) page for more details.

See the [AEM Operations Dashboard](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/operations/operations-dashboard.html) documentation for how to add such active HealthCheck services to the AEM dashboard pages - as that page says it is necessary to insert entries in the Dashboard's configuration nodes to select what's displayed on those pages.

Comment: Thanks For the answer Bertrand.. 
Links are pretty helpful. :)
Now I am able to see my custom health checks on sling console.

Though I was wondering, is it possible to configure health check for UI components(Say image) created from CRX DE??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "configuring health checks for UI components", what's your use case?